# Big sur update not happening

Tags: software-update, big-sur

Help!
I am on mojave and trying to update to big sur, and it is showing that 12 out of 12 gb has been downloaded, But it is still saying "Installing new updates and the progress bar is not progressing.
I am attaching the image below:
[image]

Comment: How long have you waited? Looks like there's still a way to go on the thermometer.

Comment: Cancel it, reboot, and try again.