# Big Sur update keeps redownloading

Tags: software-update, big-sur

I have been trying to update to Big Sur all morning but it keeps getting reset.

So far, it has used up over 40GB data by re-downloading the update again and again. It gets to 12.21GB and stays there for a while and gets reset to show that an update is available.

When I click to update, it starts downloading all over again. Getting sick of this nonsense and there are a few questions on the site like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411869/big-sur-update-not-happening) but none of them have an answer. So, please don't mark it as duplicate.

Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: Did you try rebooting your Mac?

Comment: … and rebooting **all** your network hardware - modem, router, any wifi or ethernet hubs/switches. The symptom is of a bad download cached somewhere on the way to you [perhaps your ISP but impossible to tell for sure] - so every time you start over you get the same bad data from the cache.

Comment: @Tetsujin Could have been that. I connected to a vpn and tried it and it worked

Comment: That would bypass any cache, for sure.